# using list to store values in a kernel device

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am writing a small kernel device where i need to store values in a list. Adding first to the list work fine but next entries trigger a error. Can any one say me why ? my code is given below; i am using kernel 3.6.10-4.fc18.x86_64 in fedora 18

```
LIST_HEAD(dns_list_lp ) ;

static void add_dns_list(__be32 v4address,struct in6_addr v6address)
{    
struct dns_nat node;
INIT_LIST_HEAD( &node.dns_list);
node.dns_v4address=v4address;
node.dns_v6address=v6address;
list_add_tail ( &node.dns_list , &dns_list_lp );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to store a pointer to a local variable. You have to remember that once the function returns the lifetime of the variable `node` ends, and that pointer in the list is no longer valid.

Comment: hi,
thanks i'll correct it. i will have to use a pointer and use kmalloc to alocate memory then that would be fine. is that the best solution for this. will there be a memory leak as i call kmalloc each time  in the add_dns_list()

Comment: @user2714949 No memory leaks if you remember to free the data once you're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing the list every time `add_dns_list` is called.